# How do you make a function which sets properties of other instances in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am trying to write the following code in a shorter way.

```
func colourChangeIfDeletionCancelled(word:Int){
    for i in 0...selectedWords[word].count - 1 {
        let square = selectedWords[word][i]

    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].topToRight.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].topToLeft.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].bottomToRight.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].bottomToLeft.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].horizontalTube.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].verticalTube.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].endFromLeft.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].endFromRight.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].endFromTop.backgroundColor = nil
    arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].endFromBottom.backgroundColor = nil

    }
}
```

This code works but I am sure there is a better (shorter) way to do write it but I am unsure how. I have tried to make a function that takes the subviews as a variable but am lost on how to do that. I'm sure this isn't the hardest problem but I am stuck on it and any help is appreciated.

Edit:

arrayOfRows is just an array of arrays of a class I have created called LetterSquareView

```
 class LetterSquareView: UIView {
 var letter:String!

@IBOutlet weak var topToLeft: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var topToRight: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToRight: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToLeft: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalTube: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalTube: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var endFromLeft: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var endFromRight: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var endFromTop: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var endFromBottom: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var topToLeftWhiteSpace: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var topToRightWhiteSpace: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToRightWhiteSpace: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomToLeftWhiteSpace: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var letterSquareViewView: LetterSquareViewView!
@IBOutlet var letterSquareView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var letterLbl: UILabel!

init(frame: CGRect, letter: String) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LetterSquareView", owner: self, options:  nil)

    letterLbl.text = letter.capitalizedString
    self.letter = letter
    self.addSubview(letterSquareView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

The subviews that I am trying to change the background colour of have a background colour set when they are created. I am trying to delete that colour when they are deleted. I thought there would be a function where you could input an array of the views and input a property of there's to set and it'd just be set but I can't find anything of the sort.

Comment: What is `arrayOfRows`, what is `square`? What is the type of elements in `arrayOfRows`?

Comment: You want us to help you improve your usage of your data structure without giving us any information on the data structure. How's that supposed to work?

Comment: Did you include every subview that arrayOfRows has? Or every subview of a specific class type.

Comment: You should make an extension of your custom view doing that code so you can call a more convenient method like `arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1].everyCaseBackgroundColor = nil`

Comment: Where are you creating the views?  Can you just set the properties there?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most straight forward way is to have:

```
func clearBackgroundColors(e: WhateverViewThisIs) {
      for view in [e.topToRight, e.topToLeft, etc. ] {
          view.backgroundColor = nil
      }
}

clearBackgroundColors(arrayOfRows[square.0][square.1])
```

A good question to think is about responsibilities of the classes. I would argue the view in `arrayOfRows[][]` should have it's subviews private, knowledge of them is likely an implementation detail and not of public knowledge. So the `clearBackgroundColors()` method should be placed there instead of setting all colors from a more global place.

Comment: This is a good answer given the limited information we have to work with, but I feel a more fundamental improvement in the data structure is probably possible.

Comment: I agree. There likely is an underlying design issue which lead into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

var arrayOfRows: [[UIView]] = [[]]
let square: (Int, Int)!
```

A way to make your touple code cleaner:

```
//extracting touple
let (row, col) = square
arrayOfRows[row][col].topToRight.backgroundColor = nil
```

Only use this is you are sure all the subviews of this view you want to make the background color nil.

```
//for all views
for arrayOfColumns in arrayOfRows {
    for views in arrayOfColumns {
        for subview in views.subviews {
            subview.backgroundColor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I recommend to handle it. This also allows you to customize those views further with OOP design. Then you can

```
//with class type
//use this if there are other subviews
//make all your views in your list a CustomViewToMakeNil
class CustomViewToMakeNil: UIView {
    //set the views content
}

for arrayOfColumns in arrayOfRows {
    for views in arrayOfColumns {
        for subview in views.subviews {
            //check if they are of the type you want to make the color nil
            if subview is CustomViewToMakeNil {
                subview.backgroundColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```